# Dividing 2d array into all possible nxn squares

Tags: c, matrix, multidimensional-array

Spent hours on this allready(since im still learning), so maybe you guys could help.
The problem is that i can't figure out the way how to divide a 2d array to all possible nxn squares.
  I am randomizing 2d array lets say it's like this:

```
1 0 1   
0 2 2    
3 5 1
```

There are 5 nxn squares in this matrix 4-2x2 and 1-3x3

The goal is to give all of these squares to the function as a separate array, one by one.

p.s. Sorry for poor english

---

Simplification:

I input this array:

```
char array[9] = {1,0,1,0,2,2,3,5,1};
```

and want to pass the following arrays to the function:

```
char array[9] = {1,0,1,0,2,2,3,5,1};
char array[4] = {1,0,0,2};
char array[4] = {0,1,2,2};
char array[4] = {0,2,3,5};
char array[4] = {2,2,5,1};
```

How can I extract these submatrices from the main matrix?

Comment: I edited your question a bit, because you actually did not ask a question. just tell a story. and I added some clarification for others to understand this question easier :) Welcome to Stackoverflow!

Comment: You also left out the 1x1 matrices (of which there are 9 in your sample).

Answer (score 1):

The usual way to achieve this is to supply a row/column offset and a size:

```
void DisplaySubArray( int arr[3][3], int x0, int y0, int size ) 
{
    int x, y, *row;

    for( y = 0; y < size; y++ )
    {
        row = &arr[y0+y][x0];
        for( x = 0; x < size; x++ )
        {
            printf( "\t%d", row[x] );
        }
        printf( "\n" );
    }
}
```

And the enumeration:

```
const int N = 3;
int arr[3][3] = { 1, 0, 1, 0, 2, 2, 3, 5, 1 };
int x0, y0, size;

for( size = 2; size <= N; size++ )
{
    for( y0 = 0; y0 <= N-size; y0++ )
    {
        for( x0 = 0; x0 <= N-size; x0++ )
        {
            printf( "%dx%d at position (%d,%d):\n", size, size, x0, y0 );
            DisplaySubArray( arr, x0, y0, size );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The algorithm doesnt seem so frustrating when you use function:), many thanks i think i understand it now, just one more question - if primary matrix would be not square, this would still work i just need to give correct parameters to "DisplaySubArray" function and use some if statements in main. Am I right?

Comment: In that case, `N` would become two variables (`WIDTH` and `HEIGHT`, for example) and used accordingly.  No other modifications would be required.

Answer (score 0):

I think in this case using recursive algorithm is the best way.

Let's imagine. You have matrix MxN, and you had already processed all of submatrices of MxN. At this moment we need to extend our solution to matrix (M+1)xN - the same size, but one column or one row more.

In fact, we need to add to our submatrices some count of other submatrices, but we can do it easy. Have a look below:

```
ABC
DEF
GHI
```

extend to

```
ABCX
DEFY
GHIZ
```

we need to add only XY and YZ submatrices (submatrices, which ended by XY and YZ at right side), maybe you need in X,Y,Z submatrices, I don't know (I haven't seen them in topic start post). As a result in fact, we can easy get all of necessary right sides (for example, for{for{}} loop) for solution in general (for any N). At the end, add one loop more (from A column to C or X column).

I suppose it's clear that we got all of submatrices, which are appearing due to MxN -> (M+1)xN action.

Final solution - we start from some base submatrix (1x1, 2x2, as you like) and extend this by one for every dimension.